# data exception: string data, right truncation error

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

I am upgrading hibernate version from `5.1.17` to `5.4.11`. 
I am getting this error `java.sql.sqldataexception  data exception: string data, right truncation; table:tablename colum: columnname`.

When I check it in database, this column is declared as `VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)`. I am getting this while running a test case which has data in a file. If I reduce the data related to this column then it is working.

It is old audit table.
How and what changes I have to do on this column?

We have custom `HSQLDialect` class and I tried to register column type as

`registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "clob/varchar2/nvarchar" );` but I am getting `user lacks privilege or object not found:`

Can someone explain why it is failing after hibernate upgrade only (It was working fine with earlier version) and how to fix it?

`Hibernate version: 5.4.11
HSQLDB version: 2.3.3
hibernate-search-orm: 5.11.5.Final
lucene.version: 5.5.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hibernate issue as per https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13886#icft=HHH-13886

my column is defined as

`@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(4000)")
private int caseNumber;`

it should be changed as

`@Column(length = 4000)
private int caseNumber;`

This is change required only for Entities which are marked as `@Audited`.

Now, my test case is working fine.

see this for more info: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=31818&styleName=Html&projectId=10031

Comment: I have faced a similar issue but my entity wasn't marked as @Audited and so it is not specific to any annotation rather it is more related to the column length. If the length of the value is greater than the column size, this issue will come.